# Proper way to initialize a background service in dot net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq

I have a service that needs to connect to another service at the `startup`.
The other service is a `Rabbitmq` broker.

I'm listening to some event from `Rabbitmq` so I need it to be activated from the start of the application.

I need to connect to two different `VHost`s, so I need to create two connections.

The problem is that when I start the application is constantly creates connections until the server crashes!

In Rabbitmq management I can see a lot of `Connection` and `Channels` are created.

I can't find out why is this happening.

In general, I  want to know whats is the proper way of connecting to other services in the startup of my application in dotnet core.

I'm using this code to do so :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            .....

            services.AddSingleton<RabbitConnectionService>();

            ...

            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RabbitConnectionService>(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        }
```

And in the constructor of `RabbitConnectionService` I'm connecting to `Rabbitmq`.

```
public RabbitConnectionService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {   
            ServersMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstVhost"), "First");
            ClientsMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(configuration.GetConnectionString("SecondVhost"), "Second");
        }
```

MessageQueue Class :

```
public class MessageQueue
    {

        private IConnection connection;

        private string RabbitURI;
        private string ConnectionName;

        static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public MessageQueue(string connectionUri, string connectionName)
        {
            ConnectionName = connectionName;
            RabbitURI = connectionUri;
            connection = CreateConnection();
        }


        private IConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.Uri = new Uri(RabbitURI);
            factory.AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true;
            factory.RequestedHeartbeat = 10;
            return factory.CreateConnection(ConnectionName);
        }

        public IModel CreateChannel()
        {
            return connection.CreateModel();
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information here. For example, why are you calling`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` in your `ConfigureServices`, then doing nothing with the result?

Comment: I'm listening to some event from Rabbitmq so I need it to be activated from the start of the application. If I do not put it in there It will not be started until the first request comes to my server.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. The `ConfigureServices` method in .NET Core is poorly named, it should really have been called `ConfigureDependencies` or similar. Anyway, what you are looking for is background **tasks**, and MSDN has docs on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task-1

Comment: Maybe my answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535975/how-can-i-order-asp-net-core-runs-a-method-once-per-day/58537020#58537020

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks, You answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable Background processing, you need to create a class which implements `IHostedService` interface.

```
public interface IHostedService
{
    Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

This interface got two methods `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`. And you need to register the service using dependency injection, like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, DemoService>();
    ...
}
```

Instead of implementing `IHostedService`, you can derive from `BackgroundService` abstract class and you can implement the `ExecuteAsync` abstract method. Here is an example of a minimal background service, which monitors a table in SQL Server and send emails:

```
public class DemoService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<DemoService> _demoservicelogger;
    private readonly DemoContext _demoContext;
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    public DemoService(ILogger<DemoService> demoservicelogger, 
        DemoContext demoContext, IEmailService emailService)
    {
        _demoservicelogger = demoservicelogger;
        _demoContext = demoContext;
        _emailService = emailService;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _demoservicelogger.LogDebug("Demo Service is starting");
        stoppingToken.Register(() => _demoservicelogger.LogDebug("Demo Service is stopping."));
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _demoservicelogger.LogDebug("Demo Service is running in background");
            var pendingEmailTasks = _demoContext.EmailTasks
                .Where(x => !x.IsEmailSent).AsEnumerable();
            await SendEmailsAsync(pendingEmailTasks);
            await Task.Delay(1000 * 60 * 5, stoppingToken);
        }
        _demoservicelogger.LogDebug("Demo service is stopping");
    }
}
```

Thanks to Ian Kemp.

[Refrence](https://dotnetthoughts.net/background-tasks-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Great answer. What if the service was listening to an endpoint and it fired events when an email was ready to be sent? You would not require a while loop or delay, but I'm not sure how the asynchronous logic would be handled in the ExecuteAsync method.

Comment: @Murphybro2 I'm sure you have figured out the issue by now, but for anyone else who comes along, if you just have an even listener, then you don't need to use the ```BackgroundService``` instead use @AminSojoudi's first suggestion, simply implement ```IHostedService``` then wire up your eventhandler during Start and unwire it on Stop