# Run BackgroundService every day at midnight in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I would like to run a background service every day at mid-night. .NET Core default BackgroundService runs on `task.delay`, I would like to run this every mid-night(24 hour interval).

The problem I have the BackgroundService runs on every `task.Delay` Interval rather than Specific Time specified.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // We ultimately resolve the actual services we use from the scope we create below.
                // This ensures that all services that were registered with services.AddScoped<T>()
                // will be disposed at the end of the service scope (the current iteration).
                using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();

                var configuration = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorkFlowScheduleService>();
                configuration.DailySchedule(dateTime: DateTime.Now);

                _logger.LogInformation($"Sending message to ");

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don’t - make it a standard console app and run it via your platforms scheduler (eg crontab for Linux).  The lower complexity will be something you thank yourself for later on.

Comment: What OS are you planning to schedule this on ?

Comment: Maybe this could help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535975/how-can-i-order-asp-net-core-runs-a-method-once-per-day/58537020#58537020

Comment: @Clint i am running this on windows

Comment: why don't you schedule it on Windows Task Scheduler and have the piece of scheduled to be executed a particular `DateTime` at `x` interval ?

Answer (score 11):

Here is my solution.

```
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
 {
     do
     {
         int hourSpan = 24 - DateTime.Now.Hour;
         int numberOfHours = hourSpan;

         if (hourSpan == 24)
         {
             //do something
             numberOfHours = 24;
         }

         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(numberOfHours), stoppingToken);
     }
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

How about put in an initial `Task.Delay` that waits till midnight, do whatever you need to do, then `Task.Delay` 24 hrs?

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    // calculate seconds till midnight
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var hours = 23 - now.Hour;
    var minutes = 59 - now.Minute;
    var seconds = 59 - now.Second;
    var secondsTillMidnight = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;

    // wait till midnight
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsTillMidnight), stoppingToken);

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // do stuff
        _logger.LogInformation($"Sending message to ");

        // wait 24 hours
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24), stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is subject to drift, particularly if `stuff` takes a non-trivial amount of time.

Comment: I believe that this solution is 1 second out and it should be `var seconds = 60 - now.Second;`.
Otherwise if the current time is 23:59:59 then you end up waiting for 23-23=0 hours, 59-59=0 minutes and 59-59=0 seconds, i.e. no time when it should be waiting for 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible solution.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    do
    {
        var waitTime = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59) - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        await Task.Delay(waitTime, stoppingToken);

        //Do Work

    } while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer if you are on .NET 6.0.

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using(using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)))
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
            {
                /*
                * Do whatever you wanted to do here.
                */
                
                _logger.LogInformation($"Sending message to ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will run the task 24h from the time application has started, no?

Answer (score 0):

I use NCrontab 3.3.1

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncrontab/

This way, you can use cron; otherwise, I'd agree with one of the earlier comments saying to create a console app and run it as a cron or service directly on your server.

Here's an example of how I implement NCrontab.

```
public class YourServiceName : BackgroundService
{
    private CrontabSchedule _schedule;
    private DateTime _nextRun;
    // My CrontabHelper class simply returns a string representing a cron schedule. You can just use 0 0 0 * * * to run every day at midnight instead
    private string Schedule => CrontabHelper.Schedule(CrontabHelper.CronType.Day); 

    public YourServiceName()
    {
        _schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(Schedule, new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions { IncludingSeconds = true });
        _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        do
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            if (now > _nextRun)
            {
                // DO WORK HERE
            }

            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        }
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

Then in your program.cs include this

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<YourServiceName>();
```

Hope this helps!